# Cannot read property 'saveAs' of undefined

Tags: angular, filesaver.js

I want to be able to create and download a file in an Angular component. In order to do that I'm using FileSaver.js. Even though I have imported it in my component, I get this error in console:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveAs' of undefined`

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FileSaver } from 'file-saver';


@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

}

nodes: any;
ngOnInit(): void {
  // Make the HTTP request:
  this.http.get('assets/file.json').subscribe(data => {
    // Read the result field from the JSON response.
    this.nodes = data;
    this.saveFile();

  });

}

saveFile=function (){
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");


}


}
```

Answer (score 7):

This method worked for me. Make sure you import saveAs from file-saver and use that to save as a file. So on the top you will have this:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient, ) {}

saveFile=function (){
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
}
```

So use saveAs on FileSaver.saveAs

Answer (score 0):

declare your FileSaver with your constructor to be able ot use it

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private fs : FileSaver) {

}
```

And then just use the fs variable. Should work

Comment: You mean, I can use the fs variable like this:  `this.fs.saveAs(...)`?

Comment: I tried it, now I get another error: `Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: ([object Object], ?).`

Comment: In that case remove what you add in the component and try to import filesaver this way. `import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';`